# Monotouch uiwebview url problems

Tags: url, cookies, uiwebview, xamarin.ios

Im opening an url in monotouch in an UIWebView. When i open this URL in my browser it works fine, but in the simulator it doesnt appear to save the cookies. This cookie is needed for Linkedin authentication for the server to use it in the second url (which it automatically goes to).

How can I make sure i can receive the cookies?

```
                    NSString tString = new NSString();

                NSUrl url = new NSUrl("http://secureservice.removedlink.com/linkedin/autologin.aspx?u="+username);

                NSUrlRequest request = new NSUrlRequest(url);

                backgroundURLrequest.LoadRequest(request);
                this.View.Add(backgroundURLrequest);
```

We have also tried for the server to not work with cookies, this solution works in the browsers aswell (mac + simulator + pc) but doesn't work in the uiwebview. Heres what happens to the url:

Bad link:

http://secureservice.privatelink.com/(S(2t2e0oql1asjlzg1ck5qmqlq)F(_yVCE-SUStA1kDu5WL2EVqomeEvGKG6cBSG_uI5Z-o3km9cz9kpTcr5OIqyUpiqfWcayKCGYqWFVRJHhISwn6QByDFIQ-r2uUClh0cXTYu2bVr79ExbiAR6jYDHVo3oREIECEo8nnQhJbSXXe9eRaMy71C8cjvAqwOukIymqtQjF8Sjlz4a6T2W5KXr4d9NnAZPjERBF5zfWYkKvVH5AHxO-mQIv0zYy36Te5ZH_6KA1))/linkedin/update.aspx

Good link (What you should get, and what you get using a browser)

http://secureservice.privatelink.com/(S(2t2e0oql1asjlzg1ck5qmqlq))/linkedin/update.aspx

What is happening here?